# Error: gas required exceeds allowance or always failing transaction

Tags: solidity, web3js, gas, gas-limit, gas-estimate

I am calling contract's method from javascript.

It throws error as:

```
<pre>Error: gas required exceeds allowance or always failing transaction
        <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Object.InvalidResponse (/home/serverpro/Blockchain/healthcare/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/errors.js:38:16)
        <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at RequestManager.send (/home/serverpro/Blockchain/healthcare/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/requestmanager.js:61:22)
        <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Eth.send [as estimateGas] (/home/serverpro/Blockchain/healthcare/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/method.js:145:58)
        <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at SolidityFunction.estimateGas (/home/serverpro/Blockchain/healthcare/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/function.js:187:26)
        <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at /home/serverpro/Blockchain/healthcare/api/routes/insurance.js:86:60
        <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/serverpro/Blockchain/healthcare/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
        <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at next (/home/serverpro/Blockchain/healthcare/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
        <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Route.dispatch (/home/serverpro/Blockchain/healthcare/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
        <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/serverpro/Blockchain/healthcare/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
        <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at /home/serverpro/Blockchain/healthcare/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    </pre>
```

At below line.

```
var gasamount = insuranceInstance.addInsurance.estimateGas(insuranceId,company,plan,price,details);
```

solidity function is:

```
function addInsurance(uint _insuranceId,string _comapany,string _plan,uint _price,string _details) public {
    insuranceDetail[_insuranceId].company = _comapany;
    insuranceDetail[_insuranceId].plan = _plan;
    insuranceDetail[_insuranceId].price = _price;
    insuranceDetail[_insuranceId].details = _details;
    totalInsuranceCount++;
    InsuranceAdded (owner,_insuranceId);
}
```

What is could be?

Comment: Nothing in this code seem to be able to throw the transaction so maybe increasing gas will solve it?. However, what is `InsuranceAdded` is it an event? and the insuraceDetail, how is it defined? I am assuming it is a `mapping` of` `uints` to `struct`. If you can provide more info it would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks. It solved. Gas amount return by estimateGas funciton is low. After increasing gas amount it works.